# Chrome not showing console log messages with example html doc and separate js file

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, console.log

I was just following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdI2bqOjy3c) guide for a crash course in JS as I am going to be dealing with it in building a small website. I got to around 9:40 in the video with everything working up until this point (My sample html index page, the example JS code inline with the html, etc..). However, at this point I noticed, that when I moved all JS code to the main.js file and attempted to call it with the src in my html page I received no messages from chrome's (90.0.4430.212 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)) developer tools.  I can trigger error, info or warning messages from within chrome's console by typing them out there, and I can make them happen by having them inline in the HTML. However, something about changing it to a separate file makes something go haywire? I tried moving the file to js/main.js and altered the html to match

```js
console.log('hello');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>JS Crash Course</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>JS Crash Course</h1>
    </header>
    <script> src="js/main.min.js"</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

, no luck. I tried  changing the name of the file, I moved the script tag to the title instead of the head, none of the filters in chrome's console are on. I am using vscode extension live server to update my server in real time just as the video is, but I can't think how that would change anything as the author of the video is doing the very same. I googled around for a while to find some answers, I even ran the server in incognito in case some extension was messing with it, it even works in the live stack overflow preview, but not in my console.[Here's how the console looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJX4F.png) If anyone has any insight I would appreciate it. I assume it is something asinine I am just missing. Thanks all!

Comment: The script tag goes in the head (you can defer it to load at the end). It works fine from the example you posted. If you run the snippet you see the console log.

Comment: shouldn't you move your `main.min.js` into your script tag? `<script src="js/main.min.js"> </script>`. Look at the html at 8:00 and compare the code displayed with what you have given us.

Comment: If you read the whole post I already stated that I know it works in stack overflow, and that I already tried moving it to the head and back.  It just won't show on my live server I'm broadcasting from my VSCode extension.

Comment: That fixed it rhavelka! Thank you, I didn't realize that it couldn't be outside the <>. Even though it doesn't have to be in the stack overflow compiler? Weird compiling thing I guess, either way thanks!

Comment: @UPYoda Apologies, going to be honest, I skipped a lot of what you wrote in the end because you didn't use formatting... I highly recommend the use of new lines and paragraphs.

Comment: `src` is an HTML attribute, not JS source code. HTML attributes go into the opening tag, exactly like the `lang` attribute of the <html> tag, or the `charset` attribute of the <meta> tag. It "works" in stack overflow because you're trying to include an external script in a bad way but also putting the line into the script section. Also, the browser doesn't matter. It's a syntax error and won't work in any browser.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to put the src="js/main.min.js" inside the  carrots for chrome! thanks for the quick turn around!

Comment: This is a basic typo-type error and doesn't have to be answered. You should rather delete the answer and question in order to save the mods some work ;)